# How to change image in custom row_item inside itemClickListener?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, listviewitem

Screenshot This image explains my question
"https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhUH8.png"

Activity 
    Display.java

```
lv.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        int checked_Items = lv.getCheckedItemCount();
        mode.setTitle(checked_Items + " Selected");
        //list_item.add(id);
        if (checked) {
            [Here][1] I want to get reference of imgView contained in custom_list.xml
            list_item.add(id);    
        } else {
            list_item.remove(id);
        }
```

MyAdapter.java

```
  @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview,null);
        //TextView id =convertView.findViewById(R.id.ID_c);
        TextView Name =convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_c);
        TextView Roll =convertView.findViewById(R.id.roll_c);
        ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_c);
         imageView2 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_2);
```

custom_listview.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_2"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/popup_cancel_icon"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapters are the link between your data the Views that displays that data. So if you need your views to be changed you should update your data first then as soon as you modified the data Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter` object and your views will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

just set your imageView from your data and then call notifyDataSetChanged() in your adapter to update your view and display the new image.